# I am trying fetch data from sqlit3 database and haveing this ambiguous column name problem, I don't see any issue, need an explanation

Tags: database, sqlite, inner-join, subquery

I am Trying to fetch the list of movies where two people are star in the same movies here is the table format:

```
CREATE TABLE people (
                id INTEGER,
                name TEXT NOT NULL,
                birth NUMERIC,
                PRIMARY KEY(id)
            );
CREATE TABLE stars (
                movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                person_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id),
                FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES people(id)
            );
CREATE TABLE movies (
                    id INTEGER,
                    title TEXT NOT NULL,
                    year NUMERIC,
                    PRIMARY KEY(id)
                );
```

Query:
Running the below query is giving me ambiguous column name: movie_id, i don't understand what is the issue here,

```
select movie_id from (
        (select movie_id,person_id from (
            select id from people where name = "Johnny Depp") as x 
                inner join 
                    stars on x.id = stars.person_id) as xx 
                                
        inner join 
                                    
        (select movie_id,person_id from (
            select id from people where name = "Helena Bonham Carter") as y 
                inner join 
                    stars on y.id = stars.person_id) as yy 
                                    
        on xx.movie_id = yy.movie_id
                    );
```

Comment: The result of the CTE inner join is a table with a column for every input column, so it has 2 movie_id & 2 person_id  columns. Then you don't say which movie_id to select, whereas in the ON you did. The dotted references refer to result table row column values, not somehow parts of input tables. Typo? Otherwise, learn what the operators do.

Comment: This will be a faq. Please before considering posting read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask], [Help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation.

Comment: ok i will do that should i delet this question.

Comment: Beware, non-positively received posts count towards asking limits, deleted or not. Anyway a positively answered or accepted question can't be deleted. Edit to improve all your posts. Anyway negative scores on early questions won't put you below 1 rep. Also please search to find some duplicate per my comment & you can close this to show you researched, or close this as a typo. Please read the help links I gave that you should have read before using the site. Learn how it works. Also: [meta] [meta.se]

Comment: ok i will explore it

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to group by the movies and select only those groups having the 2 different names from the `where` clause

```
select s.movie_id 
from people p
join stars s on p.id = s.person_id
where p.name in ('Johnny Depp', 'Helena Bonham Carter')
group by s.movie_id
having count(distinct p.name) = 2
```

The issue with your query is that when selecting from 2 tables with the same column name you have to tell the DB which column you want to use by adding the table name

```
select xx.movie_id ...
```

Comment: movie_id does not exist in people table.

Comment: Got it, I didn't knew that we have to inform that.